# Add 'Zoom' Image effect on scroll (Using Shopify)

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, zooming, transform

I'm trying to add this scroll effect to BG images (Like this site https://www.rhodeskin.com/)

When you scroll down it zooms out and when you scroll up it zooms in.

Comment: You need to check it [Here](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger) they use the same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.